# Docker: Approaches for watching files and restarting container processes

Tags: node.js, docker, development-environment, forever, pm2

Are there any workable approaches to watch/reload within docker?

The use case here is development, where switching between branches may change one or more of backend, frontend or database provisioning files.

Example: I have a node.js application. If server JS code changes, I want the backend server to restart. If `package.json` changes, I want the "install" container (runs `npm install`, saving `node_modules` to a shared Volume). If SQL files change, I want the provisioning container to run its `psql` commands again.

Basically, I want to watch certain files and restart the process if they change (container itself is not technically restarted). Supervisord isn't cut out for watching, but seems like process managers like PM2 or Forever would normally be the slam dunk choice if it weren't for the docker consideration.

Comment: Just a thought: how about running things using `supervisord` and issuing a `supervisorctl start <whatever>` command when the file changes? `supervisord` will keep running, so the container won't shut down.

Comment: Hi @Kryten, so perhaps `supervisord` starts an additional process - the one that watches - and then that process is responsible for running `supervisorctl` against the "main" process when an applicable file changes?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I've used [inotifywait](http://superuser.com/a/181543/340670) to watch files before - you could write a simple bash script that does this.